# Checking image empty or not

Tags: php, image

```
$image = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg";

if(!empty($image)){echo "<img src='".$image."' align='left' />";}
```

the above syntax wont successful in returning image empty or not...if image is empty in IE this shows a blank space with link like image is missing

[image]

Comment: do you mean if $image == '' ? make sure you do $empty(trim($image))

Comment: What do you mean by empty? Like the image does not exist (returns 404)?

Comment: What do you mean by successful?

Comment: What behavior are you expecting?  Your code looks like it works.

Comment: I guess "empty" is eighter **if file exists** or **is blank**

Comment: @alwyn - there is nothing wrong with your code? - if image in not empty which it isnt - then it will echo img tag with data - otherwise nothing will happen....

Comment: no it is. if image is empty it still give a blank mark just like an image is missing in IE.

Comment: Please show the HTML code that gets output in that case.

Comment: it is working actually "trim" need to be added in between.

Answer (score 4):

While your question makes no sense, `$image`  being a string you assigned a value to, I suspect that you want to check whether that image exists and is a valid image. Try `if (getimagesize($image))`

Comment: oh actually if image is empty it still display blank in IE. it like if image is missing. but firefox does not have this issue. this is why I was asking is there any other alternate way to control image display.

Comment: it is working actually "trim" need to be added in between..thanks Abe petrillo